# Is there no better way to draw this TikZ graph?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm an absolute beginner at TikZ. I'm trying to draw a graph over a period of time. Reading a couple of posts on here and some tutorials from Overleaf, I came up with this:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzmath
{
 \vmax1 = 0.25;
 \vmax2 = 0.125;
 \vmax3 = -\vmax1;
 \t1    = 0.5;
 \t2    = 2.1999995;
 \t3    = \t1;
 \t4    = \t1;
 \t5    = 4.3999995;
 \t6    = \t1;
 \t7    = \t1;
 \t8    = 4.3999995;
 \t9    = \t1;
}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[yscale=10, very thick]
   (0, 0) --
   ($ (0, 0) +(\t1, \vmax1) $) --
   ($ (0, 0) +(\t1, \vmax1) +(\t2, 0) $) --
   ($ (0, 0) +(\t1, \vmax1) +(\t2, 0) +(\t3, -\vmax1) $) --
   ($ (0, 0) +(\t1, \vmax1) +(\t2, 0) +(\t3, -\vmax1) +(\t4, \vmax2) $) --
   ($ (0, 0) +(\t1, \vmax1) +(\t2, 0) +(\t3, -\vmax1) +(\t4, \vmax2) +(\t5, 0) $) --
   ($ (0, 0) +(\t1, \vmax1) +(\t2, 0) +(\t3, -\vmax1) +(\t4, \vmax2) +(\t5, 0) +(\t6, -\vmax2) $) --
   ($ (0, 0) +(\t1, \vmax1) +(\t2, 0) +(\t3, -\vmax1) +(\t4, \vmax2) +(\t5, 0) +(\t6, -\vmax2) +(\t7, \vmax3) $) --
   ($ (0, 0) +(\t1, \vmax1) +(\t2, 0) +(\t3, -\vmax1) +(\t4, \vmax2) +(\t5, 0) +(\t6, -\vmax2) +(\t7, \vmax3) +(\t8, 0) $) --
   ($ (0, 0) +(\t1, \vmax1) +(\t2, 0) +(\t3, -\vmax1) +(\t4, \vmax2) +(\t5, 0) +(\t6, -\vmax2) +(\t7, \vmax3) +(\t8, 0) +(\t9, -\vmax3) $)
  ;
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This feels really jank code-wise. Is there no better way?

Comment: If you want to draw a signal over time, the tool to use is pgfplots, which uses Tikz and has some similarities to R-plots.

Comment: You can use coordinates relative to previous coordinate: `\draw[yscale=10, very thick]
   (0, 0) --
   ++(\t1, \vmax1) --
   ++(\t2, 0)  --
   ++(\t3, -\vmax1) --
   ++(\t4, \vmax2) --
   ++(\t5, 0) --
   ++(\t6, -\vmax2) --
   ++(\t7, \vmax3) --
   ++(\t8, 0) --
   ++(\t9, -\vmax3) 
  ;`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
declare function={
vmax1 = 0.25;
vmax2 = 0.125;
vmax3 = -vmax1;
t1    = 0.5;
t2    = 2.1999995;
t3    = t1;
t4    = t1;
t5    = 4.3999995;
t6    = t1;
t7    = t1;
t8    = 4.3999995;
t9    = t1;
}]
\draw[yscale=10, very thick] 
  (0,0) -- ++(t1, vmax1) -- ++(t2, 0) -- ++(t3, -vmax1) 
  -- ++(t4, vmax2) -- ++(t5, 0) -- ++(t6, -vmax2) 
  -- ++(t7, vmax3) -- ++(t8, 0) -- ++(t9, -vmax3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Piecewise linear function]

Answer (score 4):

Here's an approach using pgfplots.

Using coordinates is just one way to provide data:

- sometimes it's straight forward to use them
- sometimes they just are tedious to use
- you can also provide csv files instead, e.g. from simulations or measurement

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        title=Plotting data with pgfplots,
        ylabel=some unit,
        xlabel=some time,
    ]
    \addplot coordinates {  % 1st pulse; all points could be here
        (0,0) (.5,.25) (2.7,.25) (3.2,0)
    };
    \addlegendentry{1st pulse}
    
    \addplot coordinates {  % 2nd pulse; just for demonstartion purposes
        (3.2,0) (3.7,.125)(8.1,.125)(8.6,0)
        (9.1,-.25)(14.5,-.25)(15,0)
    };
    \addlegendentry{more pulses}
    
    \end{axis} 
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to create such a drawing by hand. The tutorials you should read and try several times are [here in the pgfmanual](https://tikz.dev/tutorials-guidelines).

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    % ~~~ pulses ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw (0,0) -- ++(0.1,2) -- ++(1,0) -- ++(0.1,-2)   % 1st pulse
        -- ++(0.1,1) -- ++(1.5,0) -- ++(0.1,-1)         % 2nd
        -- ++(0.1,-2) -- ++(2,0) -- ++(0.1,2)           % 3rd
        ;
        
    % ~~~ t-axis ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[->,blue] (-1,0) -- (6,0) node[anchor=west]{$t$};
    
    % ~~~ ticks + labels ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \foreach \t in {0,1,2,...,5}
        \draw (\t,2pt) -- +(0,-4pt) node[anchor=north,teal]{$\t$};
        
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```